# Sharepoint 2013 EWS inbox webpart error 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get access to inbox mails using EWS. Kerberos was configured. But when i use service.UseDefaultCredentials = true in my webpart i get 401 error (Unauthorized). What is solution to resolve this problem.

```
   private static bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) {
        return true;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {             

            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateCertificate);

            service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            service.Url = new Uri(EWSuri.uri);


            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
                                                                      new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(
                                                                       EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false), new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)));

            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
                WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf,
                new ItemView(int.MaxValue));

            emailblock.InnerHtml = "<div data-itemscount=\"" + findResults.Items.Count + "\"></div>";

            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                EmailMessage mes = (EmailMessage)item;

                emailblock.InnerHtml += "<div class=\"emailitem\"><p class=\"emailline clearfix\"><span class=\"emailfield\">From:</span>" +
                            "<span class=\"emailtext\">" + " " + mes.Sender.Name + "</span></p>" +
                            "<p class=\"emailline clearfix\"><span class=\"emailfield\">Subject:</span>" +
                            "<span class=\"emailtext\">" + " " + item.Subject + "</span></p>" +
                            "<p class=\"emailline clearfix\"><span class=\"emailfield\">Received:</span>" +
                            "<span class=\"emailtext\">" + " " + item.DateTimeSent + "</span></p></div>";

            }
        }

        catch (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRemoteException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown:{0}" ,ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving another login or credentiales that have permission. Do not forget to specify the domain if you are in AD Enviroment:

```
exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ExchangeConfig.user,
                                                            ExchangeConfig.password,
                                                            ExchangeConfig.domain);
exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(ExchangeConfig.usermail);
```

Comment: I want to use default credentials for each user in my sharepoint webpart. If i change my code for Console Application, everything will work fine. I don't understand how can i solve this problem. Kerberos was configured, but why it doesn't work???

Answer (score 0):

service.UseDefaultCredentials = true; will work when you are logged in with your own machine when using impersonation this won't work. To solve this problem u need to get an admin user who has read permissions over all mail accounts and then then pass the explicit credential of the admin user and then use the impersonate class of EWS and u r problem will be solved